# GSO (Gliozzi-Scherk-Olive) projection and its Mathematics?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, manifolds, string-theory, lagrangian-submanifolds

**GSO (Gliozzi-Scherk-Olive) projection** is an ingredient used in constructing a consistent model in superstring theory. The projection is a selection of a subset of possible vertex operators in the worldsheet conformal field theory (CFT)—usually those with specific worldsheet fermion number and periodicity conditions. Such a projection is necessary to obtain a consistent worldsheet CFT.

For terminology, for a compact 1-manifold as a $S^1$ circle, there are two spin structures, let one be periodic or antiperiodic in going around the circle. In string theory, these are called

- Ramond (periodic)
- Neveu-Schwarz (antiperiodic)

of spin structures.

For the projection to be consistent, the set $A$ of operators retained by the projection must satisfy:

- Closure — The operator product expansion (OPE) of any two operators in $A$ contains only operators which are in $A$.
- Mutual locality — There are no branch cuts in the OPE of any two operators in the set $A$.
- Modular invariance — The partition function on the two-torus of the theory containing only the operators in $A$ respects modular invariance.

My naive question is that

> Whether there is a **mathematical branch** highly relevant for formulating **GSO (Gliozzi-Scherk-Olive) projection** and determine the *consistency of projection*?

My guess is that the "Modular invariance," "Closure" and "Mutual locality" may have something to do with the **symplectic geometry and Lagrangian submanifolds (of certain space)**. But I am not sure what is the precise mathematics to put these ideas together?

Comment: For 1) are you asking for mathematical formulations of CFT a la conformal nets, Wasserman, Tener etc? 2) seems like it should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks - I follow your suggestion and ask a new one for the 2)nd part https://mathoverflow.net/q/315262/27004